# In how many ways we can choose $3$ subsets from set $|S| = 20$ ...

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many ways we can choose $S_1$, $S_2$ and $S_3$ from a set which consists of $20$ element, so that :
$S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3 = \emptyset$

Comment: Please check my edit.

Comment: Sleep well tonight.

Comment: Is the order of the sets relevant? I mean: if $(S_1,S_2,S_3)$ is a possibility and $S_1\ne S_2$ is $(S_2,S_1,S_3)$ then *another* possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to each element  and ask, "How many choices do you have?".

Possible choices for an element :

1. $S_1$
2. $S_2$
3. $S_3$
4. $S_1,S_2$
5. $S_1,S_3$
6. $S_2,S_3$
7. $\text{Forever  alone}$

Comment: Can you give me more details ?

Comment: @user3078441 edited

Answer (score 1):

Denote the set that has $20$ elements by $X$ and define $Y=\left\{ \emptyset,\left\{ 1\right\} ,\left\{ 2\right\} ,\left\{ 3\right\} ,\left\{ 1,2\right\} ,\left\{ 1,3\right\} ,\left\{ 2,3\right\} \right\} $.
Function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ defined by $f\left(x\right)=\left\{ i\in\left\{ 1,2,3\right\} \mid x\in S_{i}\right\} $
is determined by a choice $\left(S_{1},S_{2},S_{3}\right)$ of subsets of
$X$ with $S_{1}\cap S_{2}\cap S_{3}=\emptyset$. There is a one-to-one correspondence.

So the question is now: how many of such functions exist?

Since $Y$ has $7$
elements for every element $x\in X$ there are $7$ possibles values
for $f\left(x\right)$, leading to $7^{20}$ possibilities.

In this solution the order of the sets is considered to be relevant.

Comment: I don't see how this is different from mine.

Comment: @Awesome You are correct. It is not different and only adds a workout. I wouldn't mind if the OP returns to acceptance of yours. In my view you are more entitled to that. It is his decision.

Comment: As you may notice it is my first day and I actually don't know the rules and principles here . Drhab just gave the final answer so I think should verify his answer . In my opinion the concept of these communities is for helping people and give them the right path to reach their goals (solving the problem or in abstract learning the whole idea for solving the same problems),anyway, I changed the accepted answer. Thank you guys, both your answers helped me alot .